# New ASP.NET chart control not working on deployed website

Tags: asp.net, controls, charts

I have deployed my website to an .net 2.0.50727 hosting, and the page with the [chart control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) is not working.

I think it may be because this .net version doesn't support the chart control or I have forgotten to upload some required assemblies.

Anybody knows wich assemblies are the required? Does the chart control work with .net 2? I have uploaded System.Web.DataVisualization.dll and System.Drawing.dll. I have on my machine .net 3.5 and the chart works without problems.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC RC without any problems, too. I guess it requires asp.net 3.5, and because that I don't understand why the chart control doesn't work.

Please, somebody can give me any clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hosting server needs to have .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 in order for the **[Chart Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd453008.aspx)** to work and you need to set the `System.Web.DataVisualization.dll` reference "Copy local" property to true.